# Data validation from other Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

My scenario :

1. Google Spreadsheet A
2. Google Spreadsheet B

I want a Data Validation in one cell in Spreadsheet A that it's criteria is based from a list from a range on the SpreadSheet B.

I know about the imputRange function. My function range would be:

```
=importrange("0Akd9WeCioqXWdG5CVmh4VzFrUHplSUZac3pWSGdQQ1E","Estados!A2:A11")
```

Where `0Akd9WeCioqXWdG5CVmh4VzFrUHplSUZac3pWSGdQQ1E` is the key of Spreadsheet B and Estados!A2:A11 is the Sheet and the range.

But I cannot write this or any similar to this in the criteria input on the Data Validation Screen on the Spreadsheet A.

Answer (score 5):

That's not possible at this time.

Instead use add the IMPORTRANGE formula in a sheet and use the local reference in the Data Validation dialog.

If you don't want that the imported range be at simple sight, you could add a sheet to be used for the imported range and hide that sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added a line about that and turned on the community wiki checkbox.